# How to restore 3d figure from two main cuts?

Tags: 3d, geometry

Imagine we have two perpendicular cuts of the 3d figure, that has vertical axis of symmetry as it shown on the picture:

[[image: Two perpendicular cuts and the 3d-figure, that is like slightly flattened half of the sphere in this case]]

We know all the data from which these two cuts consists of(0X,0Y and 0Z data for each cut) but we don't know 3d-figure shape. The question is, how to restore 3d-figure from cuts? (Goal is to get Z-data for every black point on the figure, wherever I want to place it)

Thank you.